# React: Boolean variables to indicate a successful fetch before rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, fetch-api

I want to use a Boolean variable to make rendering only possible after two different fetches are BOTH done. I'm quite new to both React AND JavaScript, so bear with me...

**Problem:**

Relevant part of my code:

```
class AddressBook extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      personData: [],
      projectData: [],
      hasSearched: false,
      simplePersonUrl: 'path-to-api/persons',
      simpleProjectUrl: 'path-to-api/projects',
    }
  }

  addressBookSearch(value) {
    var hasSearchedPersons = false;
    var hasSearchedProjects = false;

    if (value !== '' && value.length > 2) {
      const urlsToUse = this.apiUrlsToUse();

      fetch(`${urlsToUse["personUrl"]}${value}`)
        .then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({personData: responseJson}).then(() => this.hasSearchedPersons = true)
      })

      fetch(`${urlsToUse["projectUrl"]}${value}`)
        .then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({projectData: responseJson}).then(() => this.hasSearchedProjects = true)
      })
    }

    if (hasSearchedPersons == true && hasSearchedProjects == true) {
      this.setState({
        hasSearched: true
    });
    }
  }

}
```

Then I have this conditional rendering in the render method:

```
{(this.state.hasSearched && (this.state.personData.length > 0 || this.state.projectData.length > 0)) &&
      <div>
        <Paper style={{boxShadow: 'none'}}>
          <SearchResultTab personData={this.state.personData} projectData={this.state.projectData}/>
        </Paper>
      </div>
}

{(this.state.hasSearched && this.state.personData.length <= 0 && this.state.projectData.length <= 0)
      ? <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>No results..</div>
      : null
}
```

The rendering works great otherwise, but the problem is that the rendering happens before the second fetch is not done when the rendering already happens. **So I'm now trying to prevent the rendering with some Boolean values. That is the part that doesn't work.**

Now, I know that the last part in the promises is wrong, as it gives me:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

it's just there to indicate what I want to do:

set that boolean hasSearchedPersons and hasSearachedProjects as true WHEN the fetch is successfully done.

Then as those both are done, the boolean hasSearched, in the state would be set to true and the rendering would happen with both fetches done.

How to do this? My head is about to explode. Thank you.

Comment: You should use `Promise.all()`.

Comment: You're misusing `this.`.

Comment: @SLaks, can you point out how? I'm a Java dev :) trying to figure out js this

Comment: `setState` triggers `render` method. So before you set `hasSearched` -
 render will be triggered twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just couple notes about `setState`. From [`react`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) docs:

> setState() enqueues changes to the component state and tells React
>   that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the
>   updated state.

It means that all the time you change your state, using `setState` you re-render your component. Before you set `hasSearch` to `true` you re-rendered your component twice. So to avoid unnecessary re-redndering you should use it once after your `fetch`es are done. It's possible with `Promise.all()` (already mentioned in a comments).

```
Promise.all([
  fetch(`${urlsToUse["personUrl"]}${value}`),
  fetch(`${urlsToUse["projectUrl"]}${value}`)
]).then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(res => res.json())
  .then(values => {
    // doing something with it.
    // once you are done use setState
    this.setState({ hasSearched: true })
  })
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you. What would be a good practice way in this scenario to fill in the personData and projectData in the state? To minimize the times of state changes.

Comment: @SteveWaters You can set it at once like:  `this.setState{{projects, personel}}`